# SQL trigger raise error when sum(column1) - sum(column2) != 100

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

How do I create a trigger when sum(column1)-sum(column2)!=100(example) for each update.

Ideally, I would want to calculate the value 100 mentioned above before update and after update, check if the value is the same.

I tried this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGERTRY 
AFTER UPDATE OF BALANCE_CREDIT,BALANCE_DEBIT ON my_wallet 
IF ((SELECT SUM(BALANCE_CREDIT) - SUM(BALANCE_DEBIT) INTO X FROM MTX_WALLET_BALANCES) != 100) 
BEGIN
    RAISERROR 123 'Cannot update only credit or debit'
END
;
```

I get an exception: Error: ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification

Infact, I would ideally want this(if possible):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGERTRY 
BEFORE UPDATE OF BALANCE_CREDIT,BALANCE_DEBIT ON my_wallet
X = (SELECT SUM(BALANCE_CREDIT) - SUM(BALANCE_DEBIT) INTO X FROM MTX_WALLET_BALANCES)
AFTER UPDATE OF BALANCE_CREDIT, BALANCE_DEBIT ON my_wallet
Y = (SELECT SUM(BALANCE_CREDIT) - SUM(BALANCE_DEBIT) INTO X FROM MTX_WALLET_BALANCES)
IF (X!=Y) 
BEGIN
    RAISERROR 123 'Cannot update only credit or debit'
END
;
```

Are any of the above possible, if yes, can you please let me know the exact trigger? I'm absolutely new to Trigger, using it for the first time, but nothing I found is suiting me.

My database is Oracle.

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s : My database is Oracle, I have edited

Comment: You should also add this `oracle` tag to all your Oracle-related questions (in the future - I did it for you here)